# Why do i have this errors compilation in C

Tags: data-structures, nodes

Sorry for the inconvenience could you help me with a compilation problem that I have, the following code compiles it and it worked, then I closed all the open codes in the IDE that I use (Geany) and when compiling again I get an error, and I don't know because, it gives me these errors when compiling:

I get these errors:

```
RevertirFrase.c:15:26: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
RevertirFrase.c:44:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'add' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

and the code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
struct reverse
{
char letra;
struct reverse *sig;
};
void add(struct reverse *&pila,int letra)
{
struct reverse *nuevoNodo=(struct reverse*)malloc(sizeof(struct reverse));
nuevoNodo->letra=letra;
nuevoNodo->sig=pila;
pila=nuevoNodo;
}
void show(struct reverse *letra)
{
struct reverse *ptr=NULL;
ptr=letra;
while(ptr!=NULL)
{
printf("%c",ptr->letra);
ptr=ptr->sig;
}
}
int main()
{
int esc;
printf("Ingresa la frase: \nPara finalizar pulsa ESC:\n");
struct reverse *nodo=NULL;
do{
fflush(stdin);
esc=getch();
printf("%c",esc);
if(esc!=27)
    add(nodo,esc);
}while(esc!=27);
show(nodo);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a typo in a prototype of add function. A reference after a pointer to reverse struct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending line is here:

```
void add(struct reverse *&pila, int letra)
```

You don't need the address of (&) operator as you are declaring to the compiler that the pila parameter is of type struct reverse*.

If you remove the & operator, the code compiles. If I were you though I would replace getch with getchar from the stdio.h header as getch requires conio.h which is outdated and non-standard.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to compile without &, but I think that now it don't save the entered values beacuse at the end the program do not show me the values, so to solve it I modified the function: struct reverse * add (struct reverse * stack, int letter)